# how to use a function in a button

Tags: laravel

I think my question is wrong and I will clarify the whole topic here.
i got 2 buttons in 1 form and I've already searched about this topic.
So here it is:
I have 2 buttons the other button will go to this and the other will go to

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'note' => 'required',
        'ingredientid' => 'required',            
    ]);
    Recipe::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('recipe.index')
                    ->with('success','Recipe added to the list successfully.');


}



 public function addviewing()   
 {
    request()->validate([
        'id' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);
    Viewingredient::create([
        'id' => $request->id,
        'name' => $request->name,
        ]);
    return redirect()->route('recipe.form')
                    ->with('success','Ingredient Added Successfully!');
 }
```

And this is the two buttons:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Ingredient</button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

but when i click the add ingredient it does nothing.

Comment: First, you can't have 2 submit buttons on one form! Second, you need to know that a function inside Controller has nothing to do with your button. The form is connected to a specific function inside your Controller and not the button! If you need more clarification, just ask here.

Comment: yes, @lewis4u is right.. button type submit will only run your controller if you put action and method in your form.. without action and method in your form, your button won't run anything